# Confusion of comparative adjective and/or adverb in a sentence

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs, comparative

An adjective is that which tells something about a noun or a pronoun. And an adverb is that which describes a verb. However, I find sentences where an adjective is used to describe a verb as follows:

1. He writes slower than me.
2. He writes slower than I do.

Are the above sentences correct?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neat#h3

Comment: Another example; "Tom picked it up quicker than I thought he would.", which I think should be "Tom picked it up more quickly than I thought he would."

Comment: I think both of the sentences should better be like "He writes more slowly than I do."

Comment: *Slower* is a perfectly fine adverb. It's an error to think that the more cumbersome *more slowly* somehow works better or is more valid. Notice how *better* is also an adverb. It's alwaysly wrong to force all adverbs to end in -ly. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your sentences are absolutely correct. *Slow* in this case is not an adjective. It's an adverb. But to be even more precise, it is something called [**an irregular adverb**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Regular-and-Irregular-Adverbs.htm). Irregular adverbs are not formed by adding -*ly* to the end of a word to make it an adverb as regular adverbs do. Instead, they follow their own irregular patterns. Some common examples of irregular adverbs include the adverbs *hard* (the adverb *hardly* is an adverb that means something completely different, by the way), *fast* and *wrong*, just to name a few:

> If you want to become a fluent English speaker, you have to work **hard** on your English.
>
> He runs **faster** than me.
>
> Am I doing it **wrong**?

Notice that the adjective *hard* and adverb *hard* are actually two different words. *Hard* as an adjective means *solid or firm*. As an adverb, it means *with a great deal of effort*. The exact same thing is going on with the adjective *slow* and the adverb *slow*. *Slow* as an adjective means *not quick*. As an adverb, it means *happening at a slow pace* and is completely interchangeable with the regular adverb *slowly*:

> He writes **slower** than me.
>
> He writes **more slowly** than me.